# appending values to coordinates in array of zeros

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am generating two parameters e.g.

```
s1 = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]
s2 = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]
```

based on dimensions of both these lists above, i am creating a grid of zeros:

```
np.zeros((5,5))
```

I then pair up each of the numbers in each list so they form coordinate locations in my empty grid e.g. `(0,0), (0,0.25), (0,0.5)` etc. (25 combinations to fit into 5x5 grid).

my issue is i am not too sure how to append values into the grid based on each of the coordinates generated. e.g. if i want to append the number 5 to grid location (0,0) etc so the grid fills up.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does the final result look like? How would you do this manually or with a loop?

Comment: Are the coordinates always fixed delta and offset? If so, look into the modulo operator

Comment: "I then pair up each of the numbers in each list so they form coordinate locations in my empty grid e.g. `(0,0), (0,0.25), (0,0.5)` etc. (25 combinations to fit into 5x5 grid)." It isn't clear to me what you are trying to get at the end. Could you add an expected output for your example case?

Comment: Yes of course, so the numbers in brackets in the form (a,b) represent coordinates in my grid. For each coordinate, i am generating a random number for example BASED on the coordinate itself. The number I generate I then wish to append to the same coordinate location on the grid for which it was generated. For example: for the coordinate (0,0) if i generated the random number 5 I would then wish to append it to the location of (0,0) on my grid. Then I repeat for coordinate (0,1) and if the random number I generated for that was 2 then I would append it to the location of (0,1) on the grid.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to construct a meshgrid and transpose it so that the axises are the way you want them:

```
np.array(np.meshgrid(s1, s2)).transpose(1, 2, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question! I will give it a go.

Comment: what if the OP needed a arr = np.zeros((5,5,1), dtype=float) that with my (slow) loop around would be like arr[i,j] = s1[i]**2 + s2[j]*9 [i.e. an array with 5X5 indexes 0,1,2,3,4 X 0,1,2,3,4 with value obtained by some calc on original coords] ?

Comment: @pippo1980 Not sure why this is important here, but you would do `a[..., 0] ** 2 + a[..., 1] * 9` where `a` is the output of the above line.

Comment: .so the numbers in brackets in the form (a,b) represent coordinates in my grid. For each coordinate, i am generating a random number for example BASED on the coordinate itself. The number I generate I then wish to append to the same coordinate location on the grid for which it was generated. For example: for the coordinate (0,0) if i generated the random number 5 I would then wish to append it to the location of (0,0) on my grid. Then I repeat for coordinate (0,1) and if the random number I generated for that was 2 then I would append it to the location of (0,1) on the grid. From OP comment

Answer (score 0):

not sure it is fastest way to get it, check if the  output is what you were expecting

```
import numpy as np

s1 = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]
s2 = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]



arr = np.zeros((5,5,2), dtype=float)

print (arr.shape,  arr.size, arr.ndim)


for i in range(len(s1)):
    for j in range(len(s2)):
        arr[i,j] = s1[i], s2[j]
        
        
print(arr)
```

output :

```
(5, 5, 2) 50 3

[[[0.   0.  ]
  [0.   0.25]
  [0.   0.5 ]
  [0.   0.75]
  [0.   1.  ]]

 [[0.25 0.  ]
  [0.25 0.25]
  [0.25 0.5 ]
  [0.25 0.75]
  [0.25 1.  ]]

 [[0.5  0.  ]
  [0.5  0.25]
  [0.5  0.5 ]
  [0.5  0.75]
  [0.5  1.  ]]

 [[0.75 0.  ]
  [0.75 0.25]
  [0.75 0.5 ]
  [0.75 0.75]
  [0.75 1.  ]]

 [[1.   0.  ]
  [1.   0.25]
  [1.   0.5 ]
  [1.   0.75]
  [1.   1.  ]]]
```

Comment: Ah thank you so much, I really appreciate it! I will try your method and adapt to my code.

Comment: think I got it you need arr = np.zeros((5,5,1), dtype=float) and then random number would be like  arr[i,j] = s1[i]**2 + s2[j]*9